# JBox2D - Drawing with DebugDraw

Tags: java, box2d, paint, jbox2d

How do you draw elements with JBox2D? I'm fine using the DebugDraw, I just want to find a quick way to do this in Java since I haven't worked much with graphics.

Do I need to use a Canvas? Or a JFrame? And how does the world know when I call

```
world.drawDebugData()
```

where to draw it to?

How could I devise a class that just drew points where I want them, and integrate this with JBox2D?

```
...

while(true)
    world.step(timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
    Vec2 position = body.getPosition();
    float angle = body.getAngle();
    System.out.printf("%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f\n", position.x, position.y, angle);
}
```

I imagine I could put this code somewhere inside this while loop, but I'm not exactly sure where. Is there a function that's called every time a World steps? Can I put a draw function in there? I'm even ok using the DebugDraw if I could figure it out...

Could you please help me understand what kind of class would take all the objects in the World object and draw them continually? (and where to draw to?)

Comment: Take a look at this. It was in C++, but basically the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111321/box2d-how-to-manually-render-a-body

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Thanks! So how would I use the DrawBody class? And what is the SDL_Surface *buffer? I'll be happy to mark your answer as correct and upvote it!

Comment: SDL is a C++ library used to create games in most cases. However, you could replace the rendering logic by some OpenGL or Java Graphics. My post shows how to determine the position of the vertices of polygons in the Box2D world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know where to organize everything if you're not used to programming games and physics engines.

Dyn4j is another great physics library that has great examples explaining where to put everything and even how the user can interact with the world. A lot about the dyn4j library is identical to box2d/jbox2d, so if you just try out their examples real quick, it will lend a hand to figuring out how to render graphics in box2d.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create new testbed tests, this is the best way to test out your new physics ideas and not worry about drawing and GUI stuff.  It even supports adding extra real-time options.  Check it out here:
https://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/wiki/Testbed

Comment: I' open to using testbed, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do my own implementation. Any help?

Comment: You can copy any test in there, they're all included.